# How do i paste my scraped data into a python dictionary (csv?)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'am a beginner in this so i try to learn from youtube and stack overflow. I'm currently stuck.

I'am scraping a website using a python scraper.
Now i want to put the results of the scraper into a dictionary using Python. I choose .csv so i can easy build some type of search function within my site so people can search the .csv and the website shows them their search results. I already have something that creates the .csv, only there is nothing inside when i run it..... Any

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

scraped_data=[]
details= {}


page=requests.get('https://www.swisssense.nl/bedden')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
products = soup.find_all("a", class_="product-item-link")
prices = soup.find_all("span", class_="price")
images = soup.find_all("img", class_="product-image-photo")


bed_data = soup.find_all('li', attrs={'class', 'item product product-item'})


for bed in bed_data:
    swisssense_details = {} 
    bed_naam = bed.find("a", class_="product-item-link").getText()
    bed_price = bed.find("span", class_="price").getText()  # print(bed_naam.text, bed_price.text)
    print(bed_naam, bed_price)
    scraped_data.append(swisssense_details)

dataFrame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(scraped_data)
dataFrame.to_csv('swisssense_details.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't add anything to `scraped_data` list (empty dictionary):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

scraped_data = []
details = {}


page = requests.get("https://www.swisssense.nl/bedden")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
products = soup.find_all("a", class_="product-item-link")
prices = soup.find_all("span", class_="price")
images = soup.find_all("img", class_="product-image-photo")


bed_data = soup.find_all("li", attrs={"class", "item product product-item"})


for bed in bed_data:
    bed_naam = bed.find("a", class_="product-item-link").getText()
    bed_price = bed.find(
        "span", class_="price"
    ).getText()  # print(bed_naam.text, bed_price.text)
    scraped_data.append(
        {"bed_naam": bed_naam.strip(), "bed_price": bed_price.strip()}
    )

dataFrame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(scraped_data)
dataFrame.to_csv("swisssense_details.csv", index=False)
```

Created this dataframe:

```
                                      bed_naam bed_price
0                        Bedframe Balance Pure   1.080,-
1                       Bedframe Balance Focus     990,-
2              Gestoffeerd Bedframe Dream Moon     949,-
3                         Bedframe Balance Raw   1.090,-
4                      Bedframe Balance Tender   1.290,-
5                      Bedframe Balance Gentle   1.240,-
6   Gestoffeerd Bedframe Web-Only Dream Cosmos     279,-
7                    Bedframe Balance Timeless   1.080,-
8              Gestoffeerd Bedframe Dream Star     899,-
9   Gestoffeerd Bedframe Web-Only Dream Galaxy     299,-
10            Gestoffeerd Bedframe Dream Lunar     949,-
11   Gestoffeerd Bedframe Web-Only Dream Comet     299,-
12          Gestoffeerd Bedframe Dream Stellar     949,-
```

---

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: How did it get structured like that? My spreadsheet is all in one cell.... tnx for helping